# C++ typedef map error

Tags: c++, std, typedef, stdmap

In visual studio 2013 ultimate:

a)

```
using namespace std;
typedef map<string, double> my_set;
```

> => error: map is not a template

b)

```
typedef std::map<string, double> my_set;
```

> => error: qualified name is not allowed

a or b is in file foo.h, both versions doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? 
(Yes, spent some time googling => no result, c++ is strange language)

Comment: did you `#include <map>` ? that would be the most obvious reason this would happen.

Comment: And `#include <string>` while you're at it.

Comment: facepalm, thanx guys,I thought std:: will do that job for me ...
(first steps in c++ ... it's not a java ...)

Comment: If you are declaring `using namespace std;`, then don't use `std::map` (the qualified name) just use `map`

Comment: @PaulRooney thx, Paul, I atleast this I got, this will help me with anoying writting std:: all the time. I just had mess between namespaces and includes and still have, but problem solved.

Comment: Another quick recommendation. "map is not a template" shouldn't crop up unless you have a type named map floating around your project (or a library used by your project) that isn't a template. I'd take a look around to make sure you don't have a naming collision.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you include `<map>` and `<string>`?

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

typedef std::map<std::string, double> my_set;
```